# How to free a malloc'ed char* returned with SWIG

Tags: python, c, swig

I'm using SWIG and my function returns a `char *`, which was malloc'ed.
SWIG returns `PyString_FromStringAndSize(my-char-str, len)`.

Is there a way to free this `my-char-str` without editing the C wrapper code?

Comment: Why would you need that?
swig returns a python string, which, when deallocated, takes care of freeing the memory.
If you want to delete it just remove all references to the python string.

Comment: @Bakuriu, perfectly valid question.  SWIG wraps the returned data but doesn't know it was malloc'ed unless told.  See my answer.

Answer (score 10):

Use the `%newobject` directive in your `.i` file.  From the SWIG 2.0 [documentation](http://www.swig.org/Doc2.0/SWIGDocumentation.html#Library_nn11):

> If you have a function that allocates memory like this,

```
char *foo() {
   char *result = (char *) malloc(...);
   ...
   return result;
}
```

> then the SWIG generated wrappers will have a memory leak--the returned data will be copied into a string object and the old contents ignored.
>
> To fix the memory leak, use the %newobject directive.

```
%newobject foo;
...
char *foo();
```